# Is it haraam to share picture with the opposite sex?

Tags: photos

When going out everyday people see each other. Obviously the girl has a headscarf on but does this make it ok for a girl to share her picture with guys online? Many muslim girls have instagram and they upload their pictured with headscarves on or even without headscarves on.

Answer (score 1):

going outside is something that cannot be avoided at all..
in islam, it is best that no one looks at you... so all scholars agree that even TAKING pics of women is wrong, forget about sharing them on social network websites.

When you share these pics there, they are seen by millions,,not just 10-20 or 30 like you go out.. your picture can be Mis-used by anyone. Many Many sisters had their pics found on vulgar websites,and their pics were edited, due to which they life was destroyed.

For detailed fatwa,please consult: http://islamqa.info/en/165186